# Haskell read no parser error

Tags: haskell

I've got this line of code, but it has some problems..

```
type PhonePad = [(Int,String)]
dayPad = [(1,"Monday"), (2,"Tuesday")] -- I don't list out all of them
data PhoneDay = Monday | Tuesday
    deriving (Eq, Ord,Show,Read,Bounded)
testtt :: PhonePad -> Int -> String
testtt p d = snd $ (filter (\x -> fst x == d) p)!!0
```

I want to display the PhonePad type of a number. Say `testtt dayPad 2 == "Tuesday"`
I want to get `Tuesday`:

```
read $ testtt dayPad 2 :: PhonePad
```

But it always returns an error msg:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you really need strings in `PhonePad`? Would `type PhonePad = [(Int, PhoneDay)]` be enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tuesday` isn't a `PhonePad`, it's a `PhoneDay`. Trying to read the string `"Tuesday"` as a `type PhonePad = [(Int,String)]` results in an error, because it isn't formatted like a list of tuples of `Int`s and `String`s.

```
Prelude> (read $ testtt dayPad 2) :: PhonePad
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

(`testtt dayPad 2 == "Tuesday"`)

If you instead try to read the string `"Tuesday"` as a `PhoneDay` it works.

```
Prelude> (read $ testtt dayPad 2) :: PhoneDay
Tuesday
```